# Google App Engine: how to parallelize downloads using TaskQueue or Async Urlfetch?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urlfetch

My Gae application retrieves JSON data from a third party site; given an ID representing the item to download , the item's data on this site is organized in multiple pages so my code has to download chunks of data, page after page, until the data of the last available page is retrieved.
My simplified code looks like this:

```
class FetchData(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    ...
    data_list = []
    page = 1
    while True:
      fetched_data= urlfetch.fetch('http://www.foo.com/getdata?id=xxx&result=JSON&page=%s' % page)
      data_chunk = fetched_data["data"] 
      data_list = data_list + data_chunk
      if len(data_list) == int(fetched_data["total_pages"]):
         break
      else:
         page = page +1 
    ...  
    doRender('dataview.htm',{'data_list':data_list} )
```

The `data_list` results is an ordered list where the first item has data of page number 1 and the last item has data of the latest page; this `data_list`, once retrieved, is rendered in a view.

This approach works 99% of times but sometimes, due to the **30 seconds** limit imposed by Google App Engine, on items with many pages i get the dreaded `DeadlineExceededError`.
I would like to know if using [TaskQueue](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview.html)|[Deferred](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/articles/deferred.html)|[AsyncUrlfetch](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/asynchronousrequests.html) I could improve this algorithm parallelizing in some way the N urlfetch calls.

Comment: Let me know if the solution below works out for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/asynchronousrequests.html

Which is simple like so:

```
def handle_result(rpc):
    result = rpc.get_result()
    # ... Do something with result...

# Use a helper function to define the scope of the callback.
def create_callback(rpc):
    return lambda: handle_result(rpc)

rpcs = []
for url in urls:
    rpc = urlfetch.create_rpc()
    rpc.callback = create_callback(rpc)
    urlfetch.make_fetch_call(rpc, url)
    rpcs.append(rpc)

# ...

# Finish all RPCs, and let callbacks process the results.
for rpc in rpcs:
    rpc.wait()
```

Comment: it's fine where it is. just replace the while section with the code above and alter as necessary. no globals needed.

Comment: although not very detailed, your answer helped me to focus on async solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved with this:

```
chunks_dict = {}

def handle_result(rpc, page):
    result = rpc.get_result()
    chunks_dict[page] = result["data"]

def create_callback(rpc, page):
    return lambda: handle_result(rpc, page)

rpcs = []
while True:
    rpc = urlfetch.create_rpc(deadline = 10)
    rpc.callback = create_callback(rpc, page)
    urlfetch.make_fetch_call(rpc, 'http://www.foo.com/getdata?id=xxx&result=JSON&page=%s' % page)
    rpcs.append(rpc)
    if page > total_pages:
       break
    else:
       page = page +1   
for rpc in rpcs:
    rpc.wait()

page_keys = chunks_dict.keys()
page_keys.sort()
for key in page_keys:
    data_list= data_list + chunks_dict[key]
```